# Customize Bulma with SASS in Vue.js (specific components)

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, bulma

In my Vue.js app, I have integrated Bulma successfully. I am able to globally customize Bulma with SASS, but I would like to apply the customization only for specific `.Vue` components, not the whole frontend.

I found two solutions to customize specific components:

### Solution A

App.vue

```
<style lang="scss">

@import '~bulma'; // This applies Bulma CSS to my whole frontend

</style>
```

MyComponent.vue

```
<style scoped lang="scss">

$input-color: red;
@import '~bulma';

</style>
```

### Solution B

App.vue being the same

MyComponent.vue

```
<style scoped lang="scss">

$input-color: red;
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/_all';
@import '~bulma/sass/form/_all';

</style>
```

I think that both solutions increase the payload size sent to the client due to the double import (one in `App.vue`, one in `MyComponent.vue`), with Solution B importing fewer things.

The double import is due to the fact that I have to customize the variable **before** importing bulma, as per Bulma documentation.

Is there any other ways to achieve the end result of customizing specific components?

Comment: Have you tried shared global variable on the config?

Comment: What do you mean with shared global variable on the config?

Comment: Did you create this project with Vue CLI?

Comment: Yes, I created it with Vue CLI

Comment: Then, have a look at this doc on [`css.loaderOptions`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders), particularly the `prependData` part in the example.

Comment: I had a look at it. I did it as it is described. The problem is that I need to customize a Bulma SASS variable, let's say `$input-color: red;`, but I can do it only if I re-import bulma in the component where I am doing that customization (basically duplicating the import, as described in the question)